# Шрифт толще в firefox

Tags: css, шрифты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шрифт Fira Sans, брался с google fonts и c fontstorage.com. В итоге основное содержимое выглядит по-разному в chrome(картинка 2) и firefox(картинка 1).

Порывшись в интернете нашёл решение

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  body {
    font-weight: lighter !important;
  }
}
```

В абзацах стало лучше:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом в других местах стало отображаться по-разному:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1-Firefox, 2-Chrome.

Вопрос таков, в чём первоначальная проблема и как решить её, чтобы везде смотрелось одинаково?

Comment: Это вы ещё в разных операционных системах не пробовали :) Отличия будут всегда, полностью от них вы не избавитесь

Comment: Но не такие же. Внимательно смотрите какие шрифты и в каком формате используются браузерами

Answer (score 0):

У вас точно не разная ВЫСОТА (размер) шрифта? На картинках явно разные размеры.

Вот вариант как побороть ситуацию, не изменив размеры текста: в браузере, где буквы кажутся тоньше, приделать стиль наподобие

```
text-shadow: 0 0.001em 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
```

микроскопическая тень заставляет браузер делать отображение букв чуть шире и можно подобрать нужный вид. Чем больше размер букв, тем менее заметен эффект.